# color: transparent is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

`color: transparent` is working in Firefox, but it's not working in Internet Explorer. What else I can use to make the font color transparent?

Comment: Why? If the font is set to transparent, it'll be invisible. You may as well use `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: Please add much much more detail about your situation. Show the HTML code you are using. And which IE version you are talking about.

Comment: LOL, I'm guessing piku wants a sort of "cut-out" effect where the text block is solid, but the background shows through the text itself.

Comment: @Eric, this is needed when changing button layout (e.g. <input type="button" value="Send" />) and you don't want or can't modify the HTML structure (e.g., Wordpress plugins). Your only choice is to do it in CSS. background: url('button.png'); color: transparent;

Comment: @Pekka, the question is clear, what more information do you need? He just want to make a text go transparent.

Comment: @azure_ardee: No it isn't! In the case where that happens, the done thing is to use `text-indent`

Comment: @Eric I guess that will work, but I think the practice is frowned upon: http://luigimontanez.com/2010/stop-using-text-indent-css-trick/

Comment: @azure_ardee: That's unfortunate. Looks like its only frowned upon because it's misused. There doesn't seem to be an issue per se with using it.

Comment: @Eric, I may have misuderstood, but you are suggestiong to use text-indent: -999999999px; to have the submit button label to go offscreen, right?

Comment: @azure: Right. What I'm trying to say is that the practice is in principle fine, only it has a bad reputation. I suspect google is intelligent enough not to blacklist a site just because it has a text-indent of two words on a button element. So in this case, I don't reckon there's a problem.

Answer (score 4):

According to [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-color) the color property doesn't have transparent value defined, so IE behavior is correct. If you want to have invisible element, use visibility: hidden.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.5)
```

where 0.5 is opacity level instead of

```
#hexcodes
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `visibility: hidden`. The element will take up the same space, but it will be invisible. `visibility` is supported in IE 5+ as well as all major browsers.

See: [CSS Compatibility and Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024.aspx)

Comment: +1 Not the best answer to the question, but probably the best solution for the problem.

Comment: @MvanGeest - In question it's not clear is OP need 100% transparency

Answer (score 1):

well - browsers interpret many things differently... the ie is the worst case in this scenario... you will see ^^
even different versions of the same browser will react differently!!! so it is important that you tell us, which exact version of ie you mean!

in your case: try

```
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
```

Comment: What's so special about the number 60?

Comment: @Eric: It means 60%. 100% means fully opaque and 0% means fully transparent.

Answer (score 1):

use ie filters http://www.ssi-developer.net/css/visual-filters.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You can use this technique

http://www.expression-web-designer-help.com/expression_web_helpTrans.htm

set transparency according to your needs

```
.transparent_class {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
```