# Display first letter only

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Lets say this markup:

```
<div id="socialMedia">
    <a class="Twitter">Twitter</a>
</div>
```

What i want is only to be visible the first letter of the text (in this case, just a T)

(Actually I won't end up using it but I am curious about this; sure can be helpfull later)

So this was my a attempt:

```
#socialMedia .Twitter{
    display:none;
}
#socialMedia .Twitter:first-letter {
    display: block !important;
}
```

I was able to check that it won't achieve it. Question is why? and is there some work-around this?

-EDIT-

We are looking for IE=+7/8 version capable solutions..

Salut

Comment: BTW, is this pseudo-element o pseudo-class or?

Comment: What you're doing is like hiding a parent element and trying to show one of its children, it won't work because the parent's style overrides it. The parent element also has to be a block level element for it to work. Like a `div` or `p` tag, or `display: block` on the `a` tag.

Comment: @sachleen color, maybe? (transparent VS custom)

Comment: Make sure you read the spec, your answer is there. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-letter

Comment: `The :first-letter pseudo-element applies to block container elements.`, particularly.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for clarifying, I submitted an answer that was more explicit.

Comment: @raina77ow so how would you tagg the question? cheers

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Edit: Disclaimer: this does not work according to comments. Please don't use as-is without checking it fits your needs.**

If you check the specification for the `:first-letter` pseudo-element, you'll notice the following:

> The :first-letter pseudo-element must select the first letter of the first line of a block, if it is not preceded by any other content (such as images or inline tables) on its line.

The important word here is "block."

You are trying to use the pseudo-element on an `<a/>` tag with class of `Twitter`. By default, anchor tags are inline elements (not block level elements).

For your given markup, one solution to your problem would be to style the anchor this way:

```
.Twitter {
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.Twitter:first-letter {
    visibility:visible;
}​
```

I'm not sure exactly what you are going for, but that is good enough for experimental purposes. Check out a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/H7jhF/.

Comment: Hm, that's strange. The spec on `visibility:hidden` says "descendants of the element will be visible if they have 'visibility: visible'" (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#visibility). I'll look around a bit and see if I figure out the issue. Keep in mind this is still a silly a solution because the `visibility` property doesn't eliminate the element's box.

Comment: This works in chrome, but not IE9 for some reason. Microsoft says it is supported, but that doesn't seem to be the case. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Updated by my answer to refer to the comments. Don't have time to fix or look for a fix at the moment.

Comment: It doesn't work, cause the spec allows only some properties inside `::first-letter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter. `visibility` is not one of them.

Comment: If you will use `visibility:hidden;` you might not be able to align text correctly. I would suggest to use `font-size: 0;` so letters will not take space at all;

Answer (score 38):

Try something like this:

```css
.Twitter {
  font-size: 0;
}

.Twitter:first-letter {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Twitter">Twitter</div>
```

Maybe this is not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: I used @tjeezy's jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/H7jhF/89/) and edited it to use the font size as you proposed and also set it to an inline-block so another element can flow after it.  In short i prefer using the font size.

Comment: this works and letters (other then the first) don't take any space

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to use `color: transparent`

```css
.twitter{
  display: block;
  color: transparent;
}

.twitter:first-letter{
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="socialMedia">
    <a class="twitter">Twitter</a>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygunfy5g/)

---

However, this won't work for **lte** IE8.

References:

- [IE7 IE8 IE9 `color:transparent` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110547/ie7-ie8-ie9-colortransparent-property)
- [`color: transparent` is not working in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171586/color-transparent-is-not-working-in-internet-explorer.)

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is like hiding a parent element and trying to show one of its children, it won't work because the parent's style overrides it. The parent element also has to be a block level element for it to work. Like a `div` or `p` tag, or `display: block;` on the `a` tag.

Here's something using color:

HTML

```
<div id="socialMedia">
    <a class="Twitter">Twitter</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color:#FFF;
}
.Twitter{
    display: block;
    color:#FFF;
}
.Twitter:first-letter {
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post something along these lines. Here is a little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H7jhF/. Also, to OP, check out the spec when you think something that should work doesn't (in this case: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-letter)

Comment: @tjeezy ah yes, I was looking at visibility but it didn't work but I hadn't figured out the display block yet. You should post that as an answer as it's better than mine.

Comment: Your answer was good, though. Oh well, I submitted one as well.

Comment: Yes; I should i've thought about color instead; less depending.. Anyway; Instead of setting color to white; better to transparent in default.. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Issue is that if you change the color, the letters that you don't want to see still take up space. I liked the font-size one better.

Answer (score 2):

shoot the content off the page and show the letter using dynamic content:

```
  
.twitter{
    text-indent:-9999px;
    display:block; 
    position:relative;
}
.twitter:before,.twitter::before{
    content:"T";
     position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    height:15px;
    z-index:100; 
    text-indent:9999px;
}
```

at play in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/H7jhF/67/

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use JavaScript and split the string into an array and use the first item in the array. Or charAt()

Answer (score 1):

The pure-CSS answers use visibility and color tricks to hide the remaining letters, but they are still present and affecting layout. It could cause layout issues, e.g. if you wish to float the element and put something beside it.

I found a funny way to do this without hidden elements. The trick is to shrink the entire word down to almost nothing and then blow up just the first letter. It's a bit like OP was trying to do, but it works because it's operating on a continuous spectrum rather than `display: none` which just shuts down anything inside it. (Kind of an analogue > digital situation.)

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/fafiyi/1/edit?html,css,output)

HTML:

```
<div>Ding Dong</div> and other stuff
```

CSS:

```
div {
  font-size: 0.0000016px;
  float: left;
}

div::first-letter {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10000000em;
}
```

Result:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3WeNZ55.png]

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox 62 - D isn't displayed at all.

Comment: It does work here, but Firefox's minimum font size feature is playing up. The div is taking up as much space as if you had had font-size:9px.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

```
.Twitter{
        display:block;
        width:1ch;
        overflow:hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Comment: Using a width of 1ch works with fixed-width fonts. However, when using proportional fonts, a width of 1ch can be wider or narrower than one character, width the result that the first letter may be unexpectedly truncated, or the second character may be unexpectedly exposed.

Comment: @DanielKauffman, I think that the 'ch' unit deals with the character width without the spacing so we should be good.

Comment: The 'ch' unit is relative to the width of the 'zero' character. In a fixed-width font, all of the characters are the same width, so 1ch is always exactly one character wide. However, in a proportional font, the 'zero' character may be wider (usually) or narrower (occasionally) than other characters, so 1ch is only _approximately_ the width of one character. Most of the time, this would be close enough for everything to work out. But the difference is something to be aware of.